# HTML align text under image tag

Tags: html

How can I get a figure caption to align right under an image within a div?  I doesn't have to be a caption tag. Any tag that will align the text will do.  I've tried the following but it distorts everything within my div:

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
      <span>
        <img src="/images/<%= record.logo %>" alt=<% record.logo %> height="80" width="80"  onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
        <figure><%= record.randomtext%> - <%= record.randomdate%></figure>
      </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused on how to use the [`figure` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure). The `figure` element should go around the `img` and a `figcaption` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `figure` like this

```
<div>
<figure>
  <img src="image_url" width="100" height="100">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Something.</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`.

Note when using `figcaption`, it should ideally be the first or last element within your `figure` structure.

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
      <figure>
           <img src="/images/<%= record.logo %>" alt=<% record.logo %> height="80" width="80"  onerror="this.style.display='none'" >
         <figcaption>
            <%= record.randomtext%> - <%= record.randomdate%>
         <figcaption>
     </figure>
 </div>
```

Then in your CSS you can do something like:

```
figure, figcaption {
   display:block } 

figure {
   width:100% }

figcaption {
   text-align:center }
```